# 2.1.6 Spring Boot - Elasticsearch Healthcheck failure

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, elasticsearch

***Update - I found a useful StackOverflow post where other people were having similar issues with the Healthcheck monitor failing for Elasticsearch [Springboot elastic search health management : ConnectException: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54363302/springboot-elastic-search-health-management-connectexception-connection-refus)

It seems like the Healthcheck actuator uses the Rest client, however, the Elasticsearch for mapping, getting indices and such uses the RestHighLevelClient. We have a @config file that has the variables for esPort, esHost, and esSchema (i.e. port 9200, host localhost, and schema http), the code is below, and below that the code for the "ESClient.java" class:

**ESClientConfig.java** class

```
package com.cat.digital.globalsearch.configuration;

        import com.cat.digital.globalsearch.component.ESClient;
        import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ESClientConfig {

    @Value("${elasticSearch.host}")
    private String esHost;

    @Value("${elasticSearch.port}")
    private int esPort;

    @Value("${elasticSearch.scheme}")
    private String esScheme;

    @Bean
    public ESClient esClient() {
        return new ESClient( new HttpHost(esHost, esPort, esScheme));
    }
}
```

**ESClient.java** class

```
package com.cat.digital.globalsearch.component;

import com.cat.digital.globalsearch.model.IndexDocument;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener;
import org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.delete.DeleteIndexRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.AcknowledgedResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.indices.CreateIndexRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.client.indices.GetIndexRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.client.indices.PutMappingRequest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import static org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions.DEFAULT;
import static org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentType.JSON;

/**
 * Wrapper around {@link RestHighLevelClient}
 */
public class ESClient {

    private final RestClientBuilder builder;
    private final RestHighLevelClient searchClient;

    public ESClient(HttpHost... hosts) {
        this.builder = RestClient.builder(hosts);
        searchClient = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(hosts));
    }

/**
     * @param index String represents index name in ES
     * @return true if index exists, false if not
     */
    public boolean hasIndex(String index) throws IOException {
        final GetIndexRequest request = new GetIndexRequest(index);
        try (RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(builder)) {
            return client.indices().exists(request, DEFAULT);
        }
    }
```

So now I'm thinking the "connection refused" to Elasticsearch could be because on the Dev environment its trying to use the Rest client and the correct parameters to connect are not present. But how would this explain the Healthcheck monitor working fine locally? Is the RestHighLevelClient used locally?

I posted on an issue on the spring boot GitHub, and was referred here. I will try to make this is simple as possible so I can get some help. Its actually quite simple.

**TL;DR**

- Used Spring Boot actuator to create custom Healthcheck monitor for Elasticsearch service
- Created 1 custom Java class called "IndexExists" (code below)
- Added the Application.yml file: rest.uri = ['our-dev-url-on-aws'] property

I have an application that works perfectly fine both locally and remotely, however when adding a custom Healthcheck monitor using Spring Boot to monitor my Elasticsearch service, I get a "connection refused" to Elasticsearch and the health check monitor ultimately fails. Our Load Balancer on AWS attempts to hit this endpoint and because it returns a status: "DOWN" because the healthcheck cannot connect to Elasticsearch, the Load Balancer starts to create a new Container. When looking at the CloudWatch logs, this happens repeatedly in an infinite loop (the Load Balancer attempting to make more containers). I would like to add, this works perfectly fine locally - that is, when adding the healthcheck monitor, and using a HTTP GET request on the actuator/health endpoint via POSTMAN, I get the correct JSON response which is:

**Local JSON response from /actuator/health endpoint (GET request)**

```
{
    "status": "UP",
    "details": {
        "indexExists": {
            "status": "UP",
            "details": {
                "index": "exists",
                "value": "assets"
            }
        },
        "diskSpace": {
            "status": "UP",
            "details": {
                "total": 250790436864,
                "free": 194987540480,
                "threshold": 10485760
            }
        },
        "elasticsearchRest": {
            "status": "UP",
            "details": {
                "cluster_name": "elasticsearch",
                "status": "yellow",
                "timed_out": false,
                "number_of_nodes": 1,
                "number_of_data_nodes": 1,
                "active_primary_shards": 7,
                "active_shards": 7,
                "relocating_shards": 0,
                "initializing_shards": 0,
                "unassigned_shards": 5,
                "delayed_unassigned_shards": 0,
                "number_of_pending_tasks": 0,
                "number_of_in_flight_fetch": 0,
                "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis": 0,
                "active_shards_percent_as_number": 58.333333333333336
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the Healthcheck monitor is returning the "details": { "indexExists": etc... } portion up at the top, which checks if my Elasticsearch index is mapped to the string = "assets". If it is, then it returns "status": "UP".

However, when pushing this code to the build pipeline in Azure, so I can test in a dev environment, this is the JSON response I get:

**DEV JSON response from /actuator/health endpoint (GET request)**

```
{
    "status": "DOWN",
    "details": {
        "indexExists": {
            "status": "UP",
            "details": {
                "index": "exists",
                "value": "assets"
            }
        },
        "diskSpace": {
            "status": "UP",
            "details": {
                "total": 16776032256,
                "free": 9712218112,
                "threshold": 10485760
            }
        },
        "elasticsearchRest": {
            "status": "DOWN",
            "details": {
               "error": "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can view the error logs on our AWS (Amazon Web Services) cluster and they look like this:
[image]

The java class that I created and added to our code base is **IndexExists.java**. It implements the HealthIndicator() interface and uses the actuator from Spring Boot:

**IndexExists.java class**

```
package com.cat.digital.globalsearch.component;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Health;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.cat.digital.globalsearch.data.Indices;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


@Component
public class IndexExists implements HealthIndicator {
    private final ESClient esClient;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IndexExists.class);
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();


    @Autowired
    public IndexExists(ESClient esClient) {
        this.esClient = esClient;
    }

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        try {
            if (!esClient.hasIndex(Indices.INDEX_ASSETS)) {
                return Health.down().withDetail("index", Indices.INDEX_ASSETS + " index does not exist").build();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error checking if Elasticsearch index {} exists , with exception", Indices.INDEX_ASSETS,  e);
        }
        map.put("index","exists");
        map.put("value", Indices.INDEX_ASSETS);
        return Health.up().withDetails(map).build();
    }
}
```

I won't post all the code of the application.yml, but here are the bits I added. For the spring dev profile, I only added the rest uri, the rest of the code was already there:

```
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always

spring:
  profiles: dev
elasticSearch:
  host: "aws-dev-url"
  port: -1
  scheme: https
  rest:
  uris: ["aws-dev-url"]
```

I hope that information isn't too much! I really need help... If anyone needs any more information, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Just curious...Your spring boot application was running in Azure. But Load Balancer was on AWS. How did it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your configuration, it seems that your application is using Spring Data Elasticsearch. This allows Spring Data repositories to be backed by an Elasticsearch index, and you can also get an `ElasticsearchRestTemplate` ([see reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-nosql.html#boot-features-connecting-to-elasticsearch-spring-data)).
This is what the application will use for repositories.

On the other hand, the health indicator provided by Spring Boot (the one that fails in the other environment) is using a `org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient`.
Your custom health indicator (properly working in that same environment) seems to be using something different, an `ESClient`. Maybe this client is configured with different credentials/URI?

It seems that you're not using the right configuration namespace in your application.yml file; `spring.data.elasticsearch.host` does not exist. See [the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-nosql.html#boot-features-connecting-to-elasticsearch-rest). You can see the full list of [configuration properties in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html), or you can use an IDE that supports auto-completion of properties directly (many of them do).

If everything checks out and it's still failing, I'd try to call directly your elasticsearch instance in that other environment, using a curl command for example, to make sure that this instance allows the health check request Spring Boot is using. Something like:

```
curl http://<host-in-other-env>:<port>/_cluster/health/<your-index>
```

**Edit:**

After your latest edits in your configuration file, it seems that your application is not using the Elasticsearch REST auto-configuration. You can now edit your `application.yml` file with the following:

```
spring:
  elasticsearch:
    rest:
      uris: ["aws-dev-url"]
```

With that, I think your `ESClient` could get injected directly with a `RestHighLevelClient` since Spring Boot is creating one already.

TLDR: the health indicator works locally because it's using the default "localhost:9200" address, but not in dev since it's relying on the same defaults still. Using the proper configuration property and using Spring Boot support should make things easier.

Comment: Sorry, that data: header should have not been there. I was trying different settings based on a GitHub post I was reading. I've updated the way it really looks.

I think you are on to something though. I did more research and I'm seeing other people had similar issues with the Healthcheck failing for Elasticsearch because ElasticSearch uses the "RestHighLevelClient" for Indexing, Mapping etc... but uses the "Rest" client for the Healthcheck actuator. Someone in this codebase wrote a config file with the host, port, and schema variables and I don't think maybe they are getting used by the....

Comment: *continuing from previous sentence*.... I don't think the correct rest uri for the dev environment is being used, since if its using the Rest client for the Healthcheck actuator but all are config variables are for the RestHighLevelClient. I will try testing the CURL command you listed and adding the code in the stack overflow post I linked, however I'm not too sure where to add that code (I'm an intern, someone else set up this codebase I'm in and it kind of sucks :( ) Thanks for your help thus far!

Comment: This was the stack overflow post I was referencing I think 75% could be the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54363302/springboot-elastic-search-health-management-connectexception-connection-refus

Comment: that other issue shows that this application is using both the REST client and the transport client. It didn't look like your application was using the transport client. Again, I don't know what the `ESClient` is and whether it's holding different URIs/credentials. Also, your configuration properties are still wrong (host, port, scheme don't exist - and the indentation is wrong).

Comment: I can update this thread and post the "ESClient.java" code at the top. And the credentials look to be coming from a "ESClientConfig.java" class that is annotated as @configuation with the different variables value (I posted the code for that at the top). And I think those "host" , "port" and "scheme" are used in the ESClientConfig I listed above. If none are provided, then in the Application.yml, the Spring: default profile is used with host: localhost, port: 9200 and scheme: http, but obviously that should be different in "dev"

Comment: updated my answer, it's actually a configuration props issue

Comment: Thank you, I am trying that right now. I'm assuming you wanted me to add that to application.yml as a separate property. If this doesn't work, I was also hoping to be able to just disable/remove the "elasticsearchRest"  object that is being returned in the JSON response, since that is causing the failure.... if you look above, the actually "indexExist" object returns "UP", so its actually using the ESClient and connecting to Elasticsearch successfully and checking that the index == "assets". Since the health check would work otherwise, but that one "elasticsearchRest" is failing

Comment: OK, it looks likes its working. You're a godsend :D thank you for taking the time to follow up on this post and help me. I'm an Intern, and just graduated University, so we didn't really cover that much Spring stuff (though I can see Spring is awesome!) nor Application.yml stuff and this was one of my first User Stories at my job.... Any recommendations to learn more about the yml properties and how to indent + connect them to applications or learn more about Spring? Just dive in and code and make mistakes? Thanks Brian.